# Irrational Numbers Contained in a Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, irrational-numbers

Let $k = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$. Construct the set $A$ such that every $m \in \mathbb{N}$ is divided by $k$:

$$A = \left\{\frac{1}{k},\frac{2}{k},\frac{3}{k},\frac{4}{k},\frac{5}{k},\frac{6}{k},\ldots, \frac{k}{k} \right\}$$

Is $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \in A?$ Are other irrationals in $[0,1]$ also in $A$?  I believe the answer is no, since $\sqrt{2}$ cannot be written as a quotient, and as a result is not contained in $A$. On the other hand, if some $m$ is large enough, $\frac{m}{k}$ gets arbitrarily close to $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

Comment: This still doesn't make sense.  You have defined $k=\infty$, but $\infty$ is not a number.  What do you mean by $\frac{1}{\infty},\frac{2}{\infty}$, and so on, which you are defining to be elements of $A$?

Comment: @EricWofsey At this point I've confused myself. I've completely misformulated my original question.

Answer (score 1):

This question is meaningless, because no such $k$ exists.  There is no largest natural number, since for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n+1$ is a larger natural number.

Comment: Maybe I could define $k$ as a number that approaches infinity?

Comment: @LinusRastegar No single natural number 'approaches infinity'. Sequences of natural numbers may but a natural number is a natural number is a natural number.